# Get rid of the white spaces along the edges of website header above the fold background image

Tags: html, css, header

I cannot get get rid of the white spaces along the left, right and top of my background image that i am using to cover above the fold for the header of the webpage.

I am running my tests on Google Chrome. using VS Code as my editor.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


/*Top part image background blue*/

.image-box {
  background-image: url(backgroundtoppart.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-box">Image</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`background-position: top left;` Could be worth a try rather than absolute.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply and your advise. i have tried it, but it will only resolve the white spaces on the left and top part, but on the other hand, it will make the white space on the right and bottom bigger. as i want it to be above the fold style.

Comment: You may have already resolved this but one thing worth checking is inspecting the element and editing it inline in the browser console.  It may be that there is another CSS class that is trumping what you are doing in the .image-box.  Also test in another browser to see if you get the same problem.